# Whiskey: Year is it from distilled or bottled?

Tags: whiskey, age

I've noticed that on the label on some whiskey bottles it say "distilled 2010 | bottled 2016"

Is a Whiskey in that case then categorized as a six-year-old whiskey or one-year-old (or zero) whiskey?

I'm getting a daughter this year and I would love to buy a bottle of whiskey from the year she is born (which of cause if this year, 2016) but the only whiskey I can find is where it's bottled 2016.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The bottle you are talking about will be 6 years old: it ages from the day of distillation and it will stop aging once it has been bottled (properties can change but for all intents and purposes it has stopped aging once it has been bottled)

I would even go on to say that it will pretty much be impossible to find a whiskey that is from this year as they will need some time to distill and bottle. I would say the earliest you will be able to get a whiskey distilled in 2016 would be about 4 years from now as whiskey takes time to make, so be patient you will be able to get a bottle from 2016 just not yet.

Comment: Thank you so much Jamie. I've no problem in waiting to buy a whiskey that have been distilled in 2016, I just wanted to know what the age is actually referencing to ☺️

Comment: @Mestika Glad to help

Comment: To be pedantic, aging starts once it enters an oak barrel and finishes when it leaves. It may be held in tanks for varying amounts of time before or after this.

Answer (score 3):

You can buy a cask of newly made whisky.

[Arran whisky](http://Arranwhisky.com/cask-offer) offers a newly barreled whisky, price includes insurance and 10 years of bond storage.  It's £1850 for 200 liters.  After 10 years they'll bottle it at £30 per 12 bottle crate and you can sell it or drink it.